# Include auto generated source files in Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, code-generation

I am going to integrate a Codegenerator (based on Xtext) to generate some C++ and C# files. My goal is here that I have a Visual Studio project which generates the C++ and C# files and after that this files should be automatically included in the solution and in the build process.

The solution project structure looks as follows.

- C++ Project
- C# Project
- Generator Project

The idea is:

- On the first step the generator project generates the C++ and C# files
- Then the generated files are automatically included to the C++ and C# projects

The generator is called by a target:

```
<Target
  Name="GenerateNetIDL"
  BeforeTargets="ClCompile"
  Inputs="%(NetIdlItem.Identity)"
  <Message Importance="high" Text="Generating NetIdlInterface"/>
  <Exec Command="java -jar …" />
 </Target>
```

I have tried to use the following approach to include the files for the C# project (*.*csproj* project file):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="mapping\ *.cs">
    <Link>
    </Link>
  </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

This works, but only when I generate the source files and then restart Visual Studio.

Which approach would work here? For example, generate another .targets file which includes the generated source files…

Comment: *This works, but* depends on what you mean with works: if you setup project dependencies correctly so that the generator project builds before the C# project, the generated files will be picked up and compiled. They just won't show up in VS until reloading the project (for which you don't need to restart VS)

Comment: Just as stijn comment "if you setup project dependencies correctly so that the generator project builds before the C# project", you should add the generator project references to the C++ and C# projects.

Comment: How about this issue now? Have you resolved this issue? If not, Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi @Leo-MSFT, thank you for your reply. Of course, I did set the build dependencies. The problem is that after the generation of the source files VS do not include them in the solution. Therefore the dependent projects cannot be build because there are sources that requires the generated source files. The only working way is to restart VS or to unload and load the project again.

Comment: @RomanE, yes, VS/MSBuild will cache the project file when building the solution, if you have some modification during the build process, you have to re-load the project, otherwise, those modification won't show up in VS.

Comment: @romanE as said before: I can *not* reproduce your problem based on the code shown here. The wildcards are expanded at build time by msbuild, so the files get compiled without reloading the project (even though VS does not show them in the user interface)

Comment: @stijn you are right, the code will be compiled. The description is maybe bad on this point, but the problem is that IntelliSense is not working reliable in some cases (only for the generated sources files). So, cleaning and rebuilding don't helps. Sometimes a restart of VS helps and sometimes I have to delete all VS cache files (.suo etc.). Until now I can't reproduce when this problem occurs.

Comment: There's a space in `"mapping\ *.cs"` between \ and "*" in your example code above. I think it can interfere with files matching.